# How to create item detail view with css

Tags: html, css

Htllo,

I have a specific div-tree:

```
<div class="item-detail">
    <div class="title">
        TITLE
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <h1>LOREM IPSUM</h1>
        Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="links">
        <div class="drop-down">
            <div class="title">LOREM</div>
            <div class="item">lorem</div>
            <div class="item">lorem</div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop-down">
            <div class="title">LOREM</div>
            <div class="item">lorem</div>
            <div class="item">lorem</div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop-down">
            <div class="title">LOREM</div>
            <div class="item">lorem</div>
            <div class="item">lorem</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make a css-style for that div, which will look like:

[image: what i want]

But i have no idea how should i start. Could you briefly tell me how to handle that or maybe give a short example of stuff like that?

Thanks

Comment: update your question its unclear

Comment: Please share the CSS code you've tried so far.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle of what you tried.

Comment: I have not tried yet anything :( I have no idea how to start ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite your **HTML** a bit. Like this:

```
<div class="item-detail">
    <div class="title">
        TITLE
    </div>
    <div class="info">
       <h1>LOREM IPSUM</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
        <select class="dropdown">
            <option value="title">LOREM</option>
            <option value="item">lorem</option>
            <option value="item">lorem</option>
         </select>
         <select class="dropdown">
            <option value="title">LOREM</option>
            <option value="item">lorem</option>
            <option value="item">lorem</option>
        </select>
        <select class="dropdown">
            <option value="title">LOREM</option>
            <option value="item">lorem</option>
            <option value="item">lorem</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the **CSS** you should use floats to align the columns, something like this:

```
.text, .links {
    float: left;
}

.text {
    width: 70%;
}

.links {
    width: 30%;
}

.dropdown {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/UU6Xp/

Comment: I do not need select statement in links, It should be like "only-one opened dropdown". But thanks for helping

Comment: @VinceCgto put `div.title` outside of `div.text` as the photo suggests it goes across the full width of `div.item-detail`, Taking it out of `div.text` will allow it to span full width by default.

Comment: @AbstractChaos, you're right. Didn't pay too much attention to that. Just the dropdowns which to me look like regular dropdowns instead of accordions.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Hac8G/2/

```
.item-detail {width:100%;} 
.left {float:left; width:75%;} 
.right> {float:right; width:25%; }

<div class="item-detail">
 <div class="title">
    LOREM IPSUM
</div>

<div class="left">
    left stuff
</div>
<div class="right">
    Right stuff
</div>

</div>
```

as i see the "mockup", you need a container div, a right and left floating div with a  width, if you need it. Within thoose div's you can arrange your elements.
I hope this helps

Comment: I wouldn't advise you to use 'left' and 'right' for you columns but rather more logical names. Like 'text', 'content' or 'article' and 'links'.

Answer (score 0):

.item-detail will be the larger rectangle in your whiteboard drawing, this is the container. .title, is the title, and since it's in its own div, this will appear on its own line (just like in the whiteboard drawing). .info and .links, since they are block-level (like the title), will stack on top of each other, what you need to do is override this behavior. To do that, float .info and .links to the left, and then play around with the width if you want it to fill .item-detail.

```
.info, .links{
     float: left;
}
```